# count occurrences of specific string value after using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large `dataframe` where I want to group by column A and count string occurrences in column `c`.

```
animal   weight   color
dog      10       white
dog      11       white
cat      18       white
cat      15       black
bird     16       white
bird     11       black
bird     10       white

df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
make=df.groupby('animal')['color'].str.contains('white').count()
```

The expected output is `Dog=2,cat=1,bird=2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is so called `value_counts`

```
df.groupby('animal').color.value_counts().loc[:,'white']
animal
bird    2
cat     1
dog     2
Name: color, dtype: int64
```